# How, and how best, to select a method/sub based on a boolean?

Tags: raku

I have a method in a class to return a hash, with the aim that children classes will over-ride the method. But for testing purposes, I want a different hash.
When the class is instantiated, I would prefer for the test option to be assumed to be False, so `:test` can be omitted when not needed.

At present I do this:

```
class A {
  has %.tmps;
  submethod BUILD( :$test = False ) {
    %!tmps = $test ?? self.test-tmps !! self.default-tmps
  }
  method test-tmps { ... }
  method default-tmps { ... }
}
```

This does what I want, in that `my A $x .= new` calls default-tmps, and `my A $y .=new(:test)` calls test-tmps.

But I wondered about removing the explicit check of $test via multi-dispatch. Except I could not work out the appropriate syntax. I tried

```
class A {
  has %.tmps;
  submethod BUILD( :$test = False ) {
    %!tmps = self.get-tmps( :$test )
  }
  multi method get-tmps( :test($)! where * ) {
     # return the hash for test values
  }
  multi method get-tmps( :test($)! where ! * ) {
     # return the hash for default values
  }
}
```

This does not work because I always get the test values, whether or not I specify `:test` in `new`. So my questions:

1. How to select the multi method candidate based solely on a boolean's value?
2. If what I am trying to do is possible, is there a reason (eg. run time / compile time checks) why an explicit check in `BUILD`, called by `new`, would be better than multi dispatch candidate selection?

And then, if multi-dispatch works, would the following work, or would `$!test` be False because its undefined when `%.tmps` is built?

```
class A {
  has Bool $!test;
  has %.tmps = self.get-tmps( :$!test );
  submethod BUILD( :$!test = False ) {}
  multi method get-tmps( :test($)! where * ) { ... }
 # replacing the following by whatever is the correct syntax
  multi method get-tmps( :test($) where ! * ) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what `%!tmps = $test` is supposed to do? My knee-jerk reaction is that if this is the __Test__ for the Ternary, then shouldn't the infix be `==` equality? Thx.

Comment: The RHS can be the result of two methods, depending on the Boolean value of $test. The result is assigned to %!tmps.

Comment: So `%!tmps` is a private hash then?

Comment: Raku classes have variables declared with `has` and **twiggles**. `%.` and `%!` are twiggles and when used with the same attribute name both refer to the same thing (here a hash). When `.` is used, the attribute can be accessed from an instance of the class. The Class tutorial page on docs.raku.org has a better explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, nowadays I would recommend using the `TWEAK` method, rather than the `BUILD` method.  The TWEAK semantics are generally more DWIM.

Secondly, there is nothing special about the `TWEAK` method (or the `BUILD` method, for that matter).  So they can be `multi`!

So that brings me to the following solution:

```
class A {
    has %.temps;
    multi submethod TWEAK(--> Nil) {
        %!temps = a => 42;
    }
    multi submethod TWEAK(:$test! --> Nil) {
        $test
          ?? (%!temps = a => 666)  # testing
          !! self.TWEAK(|%_);      # NOT testing
    }
}

say A.new(:test).temps;   # {a => 666}
say A.new(:!test).temps;  # {a => 42}
say A.new.temps;          # {a => 42}
```

Note the `!` in `:$test!`.  This makes the named argument mandatory.  So that candidate will be selected whenever the `test` named argument is specified.  But this also includes when it is specified with a `False` value, as in `:!test`.  That's why it needs to be tested for in that candidate.

Also note the `%_` in `self.TWEAK(|%_)`.  All methods in Raku have an *implicit* `*%_` (slurpy hash) parameter defined.  So you can use `%_` inside a method to indicate all arguments that were not caught by an explicit named parameter (such as `:$test` in this case).  So `self.TWEAK(|%_)` is basically re-dispatching *without* all explicit named parameters.

Finally: the `--> Nil` is just there to indicate that the method will not return a value.  This may allow the compiler to produce more efficient bytecode.